# managed DLL MethodNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a way to detect broken dependencies before or during app startup, but after compilation.

Suppose `MyApplication` has a code path that makes a call to `Dependency.Foo()`, which lives in `dependency.dll`.
Now suppose that I delete `Foo()` and deploy the updated `dependency.dll` without recompiling `MyApplication`.

`MyApplication` will start up and work fine until it hits a code path that wants to call `Dependency.Foo()`. Then it blows up with a `MethodNotFoundException`.

Is there a way I can detect the broken dependency and make `MyApplication` fail fast?
I'm thinking of something that would scan the dlls in the bin folder and validate the calls they make to other managed dlls. A coworker mentioned this is easy to do in the java world, but I have no idea what he was talking about...

Comment: If you're willing to build your own you should check out Cecil from the Mono project. Great library to analyse dlls. http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

Comment: @SimonC lol, I was afraid someone would say that!

Comment: Perhaps you could increase the assembly version of dependency.dll each time you update it, then in MyApplication check the assembly version of dependency.dll, if the version is higher, you know it might not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a crazy suggestion, but you could look at using [libcheck](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=11287) and ship a 'supported' store file for a given version of `MyApplication`.  Then you can validate (not sure if this can be done at runtime) and compare current store with supported store and any API breaks can be reported.

Really, the solution is to control versions via automated builds and quality gateways when shipping the software.

But as @SimonC says, cecil can work too.

Comment: [More info on libcheck](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/0596527543/working-with-code-libraries/windowsdpt-chp-4-sect-4)

Comment: Bear in mind that libcheck was primarily invented as a quality gateway tool to assist in validating approaches to versioning (like semver) - this is a very edge case suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to determine if `Dependency.Foo` exists as `MyApplication` is loading.
Something along the lines of:

```
if (typeof(Dependency).GetMethod("Foo") == null)
{
  //Fail fast, Dependency.Foo could not be found!
}
```

The same idea also works for fields and properties, or more generally, for any class member at all.

```
if (typeof(Dependency).GetMember("Bar").Length == 0)
{
  //Fail fast, Dependency.Bar could not be found!
}
```

For more information:
[System.Type on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your own add-in architecture, you will have to follow the other answers. But if you plan to use something more reliable, please consider what Microsoft ships with .NET 4, called Managed Extensibility Framework,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx

It is a general approach to design add-in contracts and allows you to handle different versions of contracts safely.